# Boot issues when using boot-repair

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 14.04, windows-7, boot-repair

I ran the recommended settings for the boot-repair tool when I was trying to link my windows 7 and Ubuntu that were on separate drives. Now my windows will not start as I get the error code 0xc0000098.

I noticed that there is within my boot folder in Ubuntu, that there is an efi folder that contains a windows EFI boot manager. How do I remove this so that I can use the boot manager that is still with my Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Boot into Ubuntu and try running this command in terminal **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>**

> sudo update-grub

that updates the grub boot menu that may solve your problem

if not then, you want to remove the efi folder you mentioned then open terminal and cd to boot and use

> sudo rm -r direcotry

you should be careful, if you remove some other files then your ubuntu will be gone

Comment: I tried that and it does not work. But right now, I dont care that i have to go to the BIOS to select my boot. Right now I can't even boot into windows from the BIOS

Comment: Is your Win 7 install 32 bit or 64 bit?